# Can one function operate on few threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a question about threads.
For example I've got code like this

```
void xyz(int x){

...
}

int main{

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
xyz(n);
}

}
```

The question is if I can modife code (and how?) in order to first thread call a function with arguments 1 to n/2  and second thread call a function with arguments from n/2 to n.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you can this sounds like a good use case for openmp. http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Recent revisions of C++ have built-in threading support.

Comment: It depends on what is going on inside function `xyz`. What is going on inside function `xyz`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution using `std::async` and a lambda function capturing your `n`:

```
#include <future>

int main() {
    size_t n = 666;

    auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [n]() { 
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; ++i)
            xyz(i);
    });
    auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [n]() { 
        for (size_t i = n/2; i < n; ++i)
            xyz(i);
    });

    f1.wait();
    f2.wait();
    return 0;
}
```

Each call to `std::async` creates a new thread and then calling `wait()` on the `std::future`s returned by async, makes sure the program doesn't return before those threads finishing.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use `<thread>` for this:

```
#include <thread>

// The function we want to execute on the new thread.
void xyz(int start, int end)
{
    for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        // ...
    }
}

// Start threads.
std::thread t1(xyz, 1, n / 2);
std::thread t2(xyz, n / 2, n);

// Wait for threads to finish.
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

If you're using GCC or Clang, don't forget to append `-pthread` to your link command if you get a link error (example: `gcc -std=c++14 myfile.cpp -pthread`.)

Comment: AFAIK `-pthread` is no more needed with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) if you tell `-std=c++14` but YMMV

Comment: I think there are even GCC versions which have it fixed for `--std=c+=11`. (C++11 added `<thread>`)

Comment: @MSalters I'm running GCC 7.2.0 and Clang git master, and both require `-pthread` (c++11, c++14, c++17). Could be a Linux distribution packaging thing though, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should **read some tutorial about [multi-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))**. I recommend this [Pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/), since you could apply the concepts to [C++11 threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) (whose model is close to [POSIX threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads)).

A function can be used in several threads if it is [reentrant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)).

You might synchronize with [mutexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) your [critical sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section), and use [condition variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables). You should avoid [data races](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition).

In some cases, you could use [atomic operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

<sup>(your question is too broad and unclear; an entire book is needed to answer it)</sup>

You might also be interested by [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC), [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL).

Be aware that threads are quite expensive resources. Each has its own [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (of one or a few megabytes), and you generally don't want to have much more runnable threads than you have available [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor). As a rule of thumb, avoid (on a common desktop or laptop computer) having more than a dozen of runnable threads (and more than a few hundreds of idle ones, and probably less). But YMMV; I prefer to have less than a dozen threads, and I am trying to have less threads than what [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency) gives.

Both answers [from Nikos C.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47741918/841108) and [from Maroš Beťko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47741902/841108) are using two threads. You could use a few more, but it probably would be unreasonable and inefficient to use a lot more of them (e.g. a hundred threads), at least on some ordinary computer. The optimal amount of threads is computer (and software and system) specific. You might make it a configurable parameter of your program. On [supercomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercomputer), you could mix multi-threading with some [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) approach. On datacenters or clusters, you might consider a [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) approach.

When benchmarking, don't forget to enable [compiler optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `-O2 -march=native` at least.